# IDLE import subprocess SyntaxError but not in Python3 in Terminal with Mac OSX

Tags: python, subprocess, syntax-error, python-idle

The following code fragment from the IDLE Python 3.7.1 Shell window on MacOS 10.11.6 causes a syntax error.
What is the solution?
The same code run in Terminal Python 2.7.10 or Python3 does not cause an error.

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
from time import strftime
import time
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
>>>
```

Comment: Why are you importing `time` twice? It seems like that is the reason there is an error.

Comment: You cannot execute multiple statements like that in IDLE. IPython (like in Spyder) however can do this

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as is often the case, is in the exception message.  You should enter one and only one statement in response to IDLE's statement prompt.  A couple of weeks ago, I edited the [IDLE doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/idle.html#python-shell-window) to make this clearer.

> With IDLE’s Shell, one enters, edits, and recalls complete statements.
>   Most consoles and terminals only work with a single physical line at a
>   time.
>
> When one pastes code into Shell, it is not compiled and possibly
>   executed until one hits Return. One may edit pasted code first. If one
>   pastes more that one statement into Shell, the result will be a
>   SyntaxError when multiple statements are compiled as if they were one.

If, in response to the prompt `>>>`, you type `import subprocess` and hit return, IDLE sends the statement to Python in the user process to execute the import.  IDLE then presents a new `>>>` prompt.  You entered three statements without triggering execution.  The only way I know to do that is by pasting all three at once.  (If you found another way, I would like to know ;-).

To run multiple statements at once, edit or paste into a file and run it.  I keep a tem.py file that I use for this.  I usually open it with Files => Recent files.